# responsiveFontSizes in theme not working for MUI, react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Would anyone know why responsiveFontSizes  just won't work for my theme? or how to go about debugging such a thing?

I've spent hours searching and tried everything i've seen (which isn't actually much to be honest as there's not much info out there for when it's not working)

i've tried importing from different packages, tried passing through the options object wit breakpoints (as it currently is), tried wrapping before exporting etc.

i'm on mui v5

help me obi-wan kenobi.. you're my only hope

[image: theme file]
[image: typography expanded in theme file]
[image: package.json]